# multi-line attributes in composer

Tags: qgis

I have a multi-line text attribute in one of my layers, but when I try to display the data using the 'add table' function in Composer, it just gives the text a single line, not enough room to fit. Have I got some setting wrong, or is this just a bug?

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a bug, it's just never been possible - see http://hub.qgis.org/issues/10273